# htaccess stealth redirect domain A to domain B

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, forwarding

Hi is it possible to stealth redirect a domain to another domain and in the meanwhile keeping the url of the first domain visible in the address bar?

Using cPanel and able to edit htaccess

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stealth Domain forwarding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509482/stealth-domain-forwarding)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this is possible, but you can instead do the following:

- Use iframe in order to display the destination website inside your current website in "full screen". Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) for more information.
- Point your domain name to the ip of the destination. This might not work if the destination uses virtual host, but you can try. Try using the same the sub-domain if this doesn't work.